# Paginating a list returned by a ViewSet in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have created a `ViewSet` class with a overridden `list` method like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyViewSet(views.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        return Response([
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 2},
        ])
```

How do I paginate this response?

In `settings.py` I've the following setup:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'LinkHeaderPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

And `LinkHeaderPagination` is built like this:

```
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class LinkHeaderPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        next_url = self.get_next_link()
        previous_url = self.get_previous_link()

        if next_url is not None and previous_url is not None:
            link = '<{next_url}>; rel="next", <{previous_url}>; rel="prev"'
        elif next_url is not None:
            link = '<{next_url}>; rel="next"'
        elif previous_url is not None:
            link = '<{previous_url}>; rel="prev"'
        else:
            link = ''

        link = link.format(next_url=next_url, previous_url=previous_url)
        headers = {'Link': link, 'Count': self.page.paginator.count} if link else {}

        return Response(data, headers=headers)
```

This works great with `ModelViewSets` since they have a specified queryset, but how do I paginate a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to call `get_paginated_reponse` method on paginator instead of returning `Response`. If this is a single viewset only

```
class MyViewSet(views.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        data = [
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 2},
        ]
        paginator = LinkHeaderPagination()
        page = paginator.paginate_queryset(data, request)
        if page is not None:
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(page)

        return Response(data)
```

Comment: @Oskar add full trace. Also this is actually a separate problem. Because as you see now your paginator gets called.

Comment: With your exact code I get this error: 'MyViewSet' object has no attribute 'get_paginated_response'

Comment: @Oskar. Sorry forgot that this is `ViewSet`. Read update. You can generalize this solution using parts from `GenericAPIView`. And creating your own `PaginatableViewSet`